# session not persisting in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I use Session in laravel, but when I get session in controller, it's not work.

web.php

```
Route::get('locale/{locale}',function ($locale){
    //Session::put('locale',$locale);
    session(['locale' => $locale]);
    Session::save();
    return redirect()->back();
});
```

Localization.php

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(\Session::has('locale')){
        \App::setLocale(\Session::get('locale'));
        session(['locale' => \Session::get('locale')]);
        \Session::save();
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Kernel.php

```
protected $middleware = [
    \App\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
];

/**
 * The application's route middleware groups.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\Localization::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EventLogMiddle::class,
        'throttle:600,1',
        'bindings',
    ],
];
```

MachCtrl.php (extends Controller)

```
public function index()
{
    $lang = session('locale');
    $config = json_encode([
        "table" => "Machine_list",
        "title" => "machine list",
        "rows" => 20,
        "column" => [
            "Machine_id", "VM_name", "Machine_location","IP_address", 
            "Network_status", "Current_status"
        ],
        "CUDP" => "0111",
        "CreateRoute" => route('machine.create'),
        "DeleteRoute" => route('machine.destroy'),
        "UpdateRoute" => route('machine.editInfo'),
        "locale" => $lang,
    ]);

    return view('table.show')->with(['config' => $config, 'lang' => 
                                                            $lang]);
}
```

I save Session in router and middlemare, it's not work.

But when I put Session in Controller, it's work. As following code:

```
public function index()
{
    session(['locale' => 'en']);
    $lang = session('locale');
    $config = json_encode([
        "table" => "Machine_list",
        "title" => "machine list",
        "rows" => 20,
        "column" => [
            "Machine_id", "VM_name", "Machine_location","IP_address", 
            "Network_status", "Current_status"
        ],
        "CUDP" => "0111",
        "CreateRoute" => route('machine.create'),
        "DeleteRoute" => route('machine.destroy'),
        "UpdateRoute" => route('machine.editInfo'),
        "locale" => $lang,
    ]);

    return view('table.show')->with(['config' => $config, 'lang' => 
                                                           $lang]);
}
```

I really want to know what happen in my project.
Thanks.

Edit:
I use dd(session()) in my code:

-web.php

```
Route::get('locale/{locale}',function ($locale){
    Session::put('locale',$locale);
    Session::save();
    dd(session());
    return redirect()->back();
});
```

Result:

[image]

-Localization.php

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{


    if(\Session::has('locale')){
        \App::setLocale(\Session::get('locale'));
        session(['locale' => \Session::get('locale')]);
        //dd(session());
        \Session::save();

    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Result:

[image]

-MachCtrl.php

```
public function index()
{
    dd(session());
    $lang = session('locale');
    $config = json_encode([
        "table" => "Machine_list",
        "title" => "machine list",
        "rows" => 20,
        "column" => [
            "Machine_id", "VM_name", "Machine_location","IP_address", 
            "Network_status", "Current_status"
        ],
        "CUDP" => "0111",
        "CreateRoute" => route('machine.create'),
        "DeleteRoute" => route('machine.destroy'),
        "UpdateRoute" => route('machine.editInfo'),
        "locale" => $lang,
    ]);

    return view('table.show')->with(['config' => $config, 'lang' => 
                                                            $lang]);
}
```

Result:[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try using a different session driver to round down your issue a little bit.

EDIT: Sorry I can't comment yet, <50rep :(

Comment: I add dd(session()), but I still can not resole my problem. :(
I don't know how to change different session driver. :(

Comment: I'm sorry it's been a slow response. Go to your .env and try switching session to file or cookie. (Even database, but you'll have to spawn the migrations for that and revert once you've resolved your issue).

Answer (score 1):

I checked my working code. I set the whole cycle as:

*Language middleware:*

```
class Language
{
    protected $app;

    public function __construct(Application $app, Request $request) {
        $this->app = $app;
    }

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $this->app->setLocale(session('user_locale', config('app.locale')));

        return $next($request); 
    }
}
```

*In my middleware Kernel.php:*

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
         \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
         //...
         \App\Http\Middleware\Language::class,
    ]
];
```

*And in route:*

```
Route::get('locale/{locale}',function ($locale){
     session(['user_locale' => $locale]);
});
```

Comment: I add dd(session()), but I still can not resole my problem.

Comment: @bookgirl create a simple route just to test your session. Don't dd() the whole session, dd the key - `session('locale')` and also the save `session(['locale' => $locale]);`